How to create a mock to a class with all methods?
In Sinon, we can create a stub to a class:
    const auditTrailClientStub = sinon.createStubInstance(AuditTrailClient);

auditTrailClientStub will have all methods the original class AuditTrailClient has.
For example, if AuditTrailClient has "method1", "method2" and "method3", then we can use these methods in auditTrailClientStub.
Do you how to mimic this functionality in Jest?
The only thing I found in Jest is:
    jest.mock('<path-to-AuditTrailClient>', () => ({
      method1: jest.fn(),
      method2: jest.fn(),
      method3: jest.fn(),
    }));

The problem here is that I have to name all the methods in AuditTrailClient that I'll need to mock. What if there are 10 methods in AuditTrailClient that I want to mock?
Is there an equivalent way to create a stub in Jest?

jest.mock('foo') marks the module foo to be mocked. When a class or function is imported from module foo in the test, Jest produces mocks for them. You can use the imported symbols as usual but they do not do anything and return undefined. You can configure their behaviour. Read more in the Jest documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#the-4-ways-to-create-an-es6-class-mock

You are looking for Automatic mock

Calling jest.mock('./sound-player') returns a useful "automatic mock" you can use to spy on calls to the class constructor and all of its methods. It replaces the ES6 class with a mock constructor, and replaces all of its methods with mock functions that always return undefined.

